# mysql access denied

Tags: mysql

Trying to find a way in by going through checklist of possible reasons I am locked out of mysql and one, I read, is to determine if I have grant tables.

```
-bash-4.1# cd /var
-bash-4.1# ls
cache  empty  lib    lock  mail  opt       run    tmp  yp
db     games  local  log   nis   preserve  spool  www
-bash-4.1# ls db
sudo
```

Apparently I am supposed to see a file named user.MYD in the db directory.
I don't even remember if I created a db after reinstall but I see 'db' there
so that must be it(?)

Is there a way I can drop the database and recreate one without access in?

Answer (score 1):

If there's anything, it should reside in `/var/lib/mysql`.

Anyway, you could start mysql in safe mode that disables authentication, e.g

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql stop # depend on your distribution
# mysqld_safe --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

Now change the password:

```
# mysql -u root mysql
mysql> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpassword') where USER='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> quit
```

Afterwards, kill mysqld and restart the service

Comment: Why do you need to start in safe mode, for security ?

Comment: @freja that disables password auth

Comment: Ok thanks, anyway weirdly I was able to get in and change username and password.

Comment: @freja oh, what you mean by locked out then

Comment: it is a mystery to me. I was completely locked out and then all of a sudden I could get in as root where before couldn't. No syntax error.

Comment: `--skip-grant-tables` does not enable "safe mode", it enables **insecure mode** where root access is granted without authentication.